# OAuth2 vk.com

Tags: javascript, вконтакте, vkontakte-api, access, oauth

Добрый день, пытаюсь получить токен:

> https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=**************&scope=4096&redirect_uri=localhost&display=page&v=5.5&response_type=token

На что, получаю ответ, в виде:

> {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"OAuth
> authorization cannot be used from
> native VK applications"}

Ссылку ввожу в браузере, приложение на локальном хосте и нормально работает в ВК.
Наверняка проблема не в этом. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в этом:

```
redirect_uri=localhost
```

Внимательно читаем [документацию](http://vk.com/dev/auth_sites):

> REDIRECT_URI – адрес, на который будет
> передан code. Этот адрес должен
> находиться в пределах домена,
> указанного в настройках приложения.
> Обратите внимание, в адресе должен
> содержаться используемый протокол.

Во-первых, не указан протокол. Во-вторых, даже если в настройках приложения указан localhost, то на какой localhost VK должен делать переадресацию? У него есть только свой localhost. Естественно, в redirect_uri нужно указывать публичный адрес, доступный "снаружи".